# Mongodb providing unique values with $sample

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to use the aggregation pipeline on mongodb to retrieve 3 random documents.

`$sample` looked to be ideal except the returned documents are not guaranteed unique.

Any ideas on how to generate 3 unique documents in response? I'm guessing it would require further usage of the aggregation pipeline, in ways I'm unsure of.

This is of course assuming that there are 3 or more documents in the collection.

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is requesting more data, let's say 100 `$sample`'d documents, group these documents by `_id` to remove duplicates (for uniqueness) and limit the output to the desired document count :

```
db.test.aggregate([{
    $sample: { size: 100 }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        document: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    }
}, {
    $limit: 3
}])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
This is assuming my collection is of size 100 or greater to begin with, in reality I'm actually growing my collection from 0 and would like to retrieve the 3 documents on every new entry. 
I'm aware that means handling the first 3 entries as a special case...
Any further ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems this question was actually built off an incorrect assumption, based on the way I was testing.

`$sample` does return unique entries, by definition, I was simply posting the same requests and hadn't realised the database had been overpopulated with this same request. Upon inspection, the objectIDs were in fact unique, thus solving the problem (which was, admittedly, non-existent in the first place).

Comment: $sample documentation states it's not unique [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample)... how did you come to this conclusion?

Comment: Looks like the older Mongodb engine could return duplicates, where the newer engine MongoDB 3.2+, will not return duplicate ObjectIds. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/#mmapv1-may-return-duplicate-documents